# Filtering Geodjango Results using Function Based Views

Tags: python, django, geodjango

Currently, the webpage displays a list of found results sorted by distance (similarly to the ListView). What I would like to do is to create a filter to further narrow down these results.

**Views.py**

```
def teacher_list(request, **kwargs):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = LocationForm(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            SearchPoint = Point(form.cleaned_data['Lng'], form.cleaned_data['Lat'])
            Radius = form.cleaned_data['SearchRadius']
            Type = form.cleaned_data['Type']
        else:
            form = LocationForm()
            SearchPoint = Point(0, 0)
            Radius = form.cleaned_data['SearchRadius']
    else:
        form = LocationForm()
        SearchPoint = Point(0, 0)
        Radius = form.cleaned_data['SearchRadius']

    results = Teacher.objects.filter(location__distance_lte=
                                     (SearchPoint, D(km=Radius)))\
        .annotate(distance=Distance('location', SearchPoint))\
        .order_by('distance')


    return render(request, "users/teacher_list.html", context={"form": form,"teacher_list":results,})
```

Currently filtering works, but not for categorical variables. For example, if I change the location or search radius, the form is updated and I see new results.

However, I have a categorical variable called `TYPE` which can be either FREE or PAID. If a person selects a FREE filter, only show results which are free and vice versa. These are boolean fields in my model.

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    free = models.BooleanField()
    paid = models.BooleanField()
```

What I tried adding is some sort of filter parameter that will work similarly to

```
if Type == 'Free':
    filter_variable = 'free=True'
elif Type == 'Paid':
    filter_variable = 'paid=True'
else:
    filter_variable =''

new_result_set = results.filter(filter_variable)
```

Is this an efficient way to filter? I looked into django-filter but didn't look compatible with geodjango and seems like an overkill for what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is it?

```
filter_variable = {Type.lower(): True} if Type else {}
new_result_set = results.filter(**filter_variable)
```

Comment: Thanks this works great. Is there any way I could use in the template.html to put selected tags on options, so that it reflects the current selected tag. E.g. <option value="free" selected="selected">Free</option>

Comment: i think yes, but i can't to understand details of your question. You can try to search it on the SO, if not success write a question.

Comment: Thanks, I need to do some research and try the code. If I can't figure out, I'll ask new. Thank you

Comment: glad to help you!